# Generalized foldr and foldl for using with generic Haskell trees?

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

***How can I write generalized foldr and foldl function for generic Haskell trees, given this definition?***

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => Tree a = Void | Node a [Tree a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

treefoldr :: (Eq a, Show a) => 
   (a -> b -> c) -> c -> (c -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> c

treefoldl :: (Eq a, Show a) =>
   (b -> a -> c) -> c -> (c -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> c
```

Even if I can understand how foldr and foldl functions work in Haskell, I'm not quite sure how to write this generalized function for trees.

**EDIT**: I tried something like this (not even compiling):

```
treefoldr  _ g1 _ _    Void       = g1
treefoldr f1 g1 f2 g2 (Node a ts) = f1 a (foldr f2 g2 ts)
```

**EDIT 2**: another try...

```
treefoldr _ z1 _ _   Void      = z1
treefoldr f z1 g z2 (Node a ts) =
   f a (foldr g z2 (map (\x -> treefoldr f z1 g z2 x) ts))

treefoldl _ z1 _ _   Void      = z1
treefoldl f z1 g z2 (Node a ts) =
   f (foldl g z2 (map (\x -> treefoldl f z1 g z2 x) ts)) a
```

`treefoldr` is working, however `treefoldl` not:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `c' against inferred type `b'
>       `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for `treefoldl' at trees.hs:47:42
>       `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for `treefoldl' at trees.hs:47:32
>     In the first argument of `foldl', namely `g'
>     In the first argument of `f', namely
>         `(foldl g z2 (map (\ x -> treefoldl f z1 g z2 x) ts))'
>     In the expression:
>         f (foldl g z2 (map (\ x -> treefoldl f z1 g z2 x) ts)) a
> ```

Comment: You say it's not compiling. Do you understand the error message?

Comment: @Dave Hinton: `Couldn't match expected type c against inferred type Tree a`, I think `treefoldr` must return a type `c`, while it's returning an entire `Tree a`?

Comment: Does the error message also say `In the third argument of \`foldr', namely \`ts'`?

Comment: BTW, strip the typeclass contexts on the `Tree`. They're useless, since you still have to repeat them everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The error message in full:

```
Couldn't match expected type `c' against inferred type `Tree a'
  `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `treefoldr' at so.hs:5:14
  Expected type: [c]
  Inferred type: [Tree a]
In the third argument of `foldr', namely `ts'
In the second argument of `f1', namely `(foldr f2 g2 ts)'
```

That means that

- `ts` is of type `[Tree a]`
- you are using it as the third argument to `foldr`
- `foldr` expects its third argument to be of type `[c]`
- `[c]` and `[Tree a]` are different types, hence this is an error

So you need to process `ts` into something of type `[c]` and pass that result to `foldr` instead of `ts` itself.  The [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) function would be a good place to start.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction, but I can't find a solution yet. I'm confused about what `f` and `g` should do. See my edits in first post...

Comment: To your edit, add the full error message you are now getting, and what you understand it to mean. It is a lot easier for us to help you if we do not have to try to compile your code ourselves.

Comment: Hinton: I finally end up with a working `treefoldr`, but the `foldl` generalized version continue to give me that error (see my edits). Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @Gremo: your type definition for `treefoldl` is wrong and as the error says the problem is with the `g` function. You use it in a `foldl` so the types of the result and the first argument have to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such a solution is allowed for your homework, but when the use of type classes is okay, you could write

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

data Tree a = Void | Node a [Tree a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)


instance Foldable Tree where 
   foldMap f Void = mempty
   foldMap f (Node value []) = f value
   foldMap f (Node value (x:xs)) = foldMap f x `mappend` foldMap f (Node value xs)
```

Using this definition the implementation of your functions should be trivial, as Foldable defines a foldl, foldr etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have talk to the same your professor, at the end I found the right solution:

```
treefoldr :: (Eq a, Show a) => (a -> b -> c) -> c -> (c -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> c
treefoldr _ z1 _ _   Void      = z1
treefoldr f z1 g z2 (Node a ts) = f a $ foldr (aggr) z2 ts
    where
        aggr t z = g (treefoldr f z1 g z2 t) z

treefoldl :: (Eq a, Show a) => (b -> a -> c) -> c -> (c -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> c
treefoldl _ z1 _ _   Void      = z1
treefoldl f z1 g z2 (Node a ts) = f (foldl (aggr) z2 ts) a
    where
        aggr z t = g (treefoldl f z1 g z2 t) z
```

Regards